# setting value for cookie

Tags: java, android, cookies

Can you show me how to set value for cookie? I often see examples of it in many codes, for example here: http://www.javadrive.jp/servlet/cookie/index4.html, but I can't do that, because setValue(String) method is undefined for the type Cookie. Pls show me how to do it.

Comment: Are you using HttpGet or DefaultHttpClient to make your request? Can you include a small block of code showing how you build the request that you want to set a cookie on?

Comment: That link you posted is about setting cookies in a Servlet, but your question is tagged Android. What are you trying to do?